# How do I view available webservices on Tomcat?

Tags: web-services, tomcat, jboss, jmx

There are two applications deployed in our project, one each on JBoss and Tomcat (using a proprietary FAST stack framework).  The following URL lists available web services / the jmx-console on JBoss:

Web Services := http: //server:port/**jbossws**

JMX Console  := http: //server:port/**jmx-console**

The same format doesn't work for Tomcat.  Is there a different module (in bold in the above URLs) with which I can view the available web services on Tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

No

There is `http://server:port/manager/html` which allows you to manage deployed WAR archives. Each WAR archive may contain webservices using different stacks. E.g. CXF or Spring-WS. Each of these stacks has different methods to list available services.

For example CXF allows you to enter the main URL mapped to `CXFServlet`, and you'll get available services.